# Speakeasy.js generate new token every hour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate a password token through speakeasy.js on a node.js express server, which shall be used as authentication. The password should change every hour. I'm using `routers` to retrieve the token and verify it.

If have set `time` to 30 seconds for testing purposes, but the token never changes.

Code:

```
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret();

var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  encoding: 'base32',
  step: : 10
});

router.get('/token/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log(token);
    var usertoken = req.params.token;
    if(usertoken == token){
        res.send("Verified")
    } else {
        res.send("Not Verified")
    }
    res.json({ token: token, usertoken: usertoken });   

});
```

Any suggestions?

*EDIT*
Added step to token.

When i request the end point e.g. http://localhost:8080/api/token/664006 the console shows the toke e.g. 290595. When i refresh the endpoint after a certain amount of time the token should change, but it doesn't. It's still 290595.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked the documentation and it looks that the parameter you're looking for it's step.
You should keep the time field to the default (Date.now() from the doc) and play with the step field.

Something like this:

```
var secret = speakEasy.generateSecret();
var token = speakEasy.totp({
  secret : secret.base32,
  encoding : 'base32',
  // leave time field to default
  step : 10
});
```

and for the verification use the method provided, instead of the ==:

```
router.get('/token/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log(token);
    var usertoken = req.params.token;
    var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({ 
       secret: base32secret,
       encoding: 'base32',
       token: userToken 
    });
    //check if the token has changed
    console.log(verified);  

});
```

[image]

https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy

Comment: Changed it to step - no luck. Please see my edit, I have added more info.

Comment: @Karim : have you used speakeasyjs in Production code. I am looking for library to generate One time passwords

Comment: hi, i've never used this library in production, but it looks pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I added 'step' inside verify code, then everything went working.

```
var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
    secret: secret,
    encoding: 'base32',
    token: token,
    step: 10
})
```